# Entity framework core : cannot open data base requested by login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core

I have given correct credentials and am sure, but i' getting this error in entity framework core code first approach. i have searched from last **2 days** all answers but all are wont work

I'm getting this error
Cannot open database **"DATABASENAME"** requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user **'MYPCNAME\Admin'**.

I have tried two connection strings using windows authentication and also sql server authentication here is the connection strings i have tried in entity framework core code first  approach

```
"HowWellDoYouKnowMe": 
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; 
user id=*******; password=*********;
Initial Catalog=HowWellYouDoYouKnowMeDb1;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

```
 "HowWellDoYouKnowMe": 
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;
Initial Catalog=HowWellYouDoYouKnowMeDb1;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;
Encrypt=False;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Comment: whats that file?. am using entity framework core code first approch

Comment: Does `HowWellYouDoYouKnowMeDb1` database exist?

Comment: @IvanStoev No, I'm starting to use EF-Core code first.

Comment: You have to first create the database in order to able to connect to it, otherwise you'll keep getting this exception. Create the initial migration and issue `Update-Database` PMC command. For more info, see [Managing Database Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/) and related topics.

Comment: @IvanStoev  thanks a lot,the example project starting to work now using this **Update-Database** command

Comment: @IvanStoev What you will do in production ? 
In development its ez to say but I want to deliver my application to an end-user he cant do this manually.

Comment: @RezaNoei Follow the docs link from my previous comment and choose what is appropriate for you - most probably [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime) topic (calling `DbContext.Database.Migrate()`), but make sure to understand potential pitfalls (vs [SQL Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts) for instance).

Comment: @IvanStoev tnx, I read that article but. when I run `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` It says `Cannot open database "Kava.BusinessDomain" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.'` It directly uses my connection string and clearly I don't have this database yet. somehow it should create that database.

Comment: @RezaNoei `Migrate` method is the direct equivalent of `Update-Database` command, and should create the database if does not exist. Have no idea why is not working for you.

Comment: After a couple of pressing `F5` it worked. It was trying to read an existing database, It failed and tried to throw an exception. After this exception It tries to create the Database. The problem was that this exception was an `Breaking` one. and to me it was an issue with `EF Core`. In other word I should uncheck `Break when this Exception thrown`. to get rid of this sad error prompt.